# Apollo-Graphql testing

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using the `client.query()` method to query from the server.
I want to write tests for this functionality using the MockProvider.

I am facing issue due to asyncronous nature of the `client.query()`

```js
// I am writing the  query as follow
const { data, loading } = await client.query({
    query: Todo,
    variables: { name },
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'
})
```

Comment: You should post your tests

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MockProvider` with `react-testing-library` to test your react component. Read more about `MockProvider` [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/).

Try this:

```js
import { act, fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing'

import YourComponent from './path'

const mocks = [
 {
  request: {
   query: Todo,
   variables: {
    query: { name },
   },
  },
  result: {
   data: {
    mockData_here
   },
  },
 },
]

test('it should ...', () => {
  let rendered
  await act(async () => {
    rendered = render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
          {YourComponent}
      </MockedProvider>
    )
  })
  expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Comment: Can you share a example of Component having nested queries,because I am facing the issue in running the nested queries in the component.Component with single query is running perfectly

Comment: @NITINMODI What do you mean ```nested query```?

Comment: Executing the first query then taking data from it then looping another query over the data of previous query